# AWS EMR PySpark Jupyter notebook not running

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm working on AWS EMR running PySpark in Jupyter notebook. All of a sudden I cannot run the scripts any more. When I click run nothing happens. Below is a screenshot of when I try to change kernel. No kernels are displayed.

What's the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell the status of your notebook from emr notebook console?

Comment: Getting the same problem. What did you do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and apparently you also need Livy installed. If I don't add Livy to the list of apps, I can use the notebook for a few minutes and then it stops working. The docs don't mention this at all, but it does mention Livy needs to be there.